# Magento 2 - I am facing this every time I run upgrade and deploy command after applying changes

Tags: magento2, cache, static-content-deploy, setup-upgrade, setup-di-compile

Each time I deploy some changes and  run,

```
upgrade
compile 
deploy
reindex
cache clean
```

commands I face these issues?

Anyone ??

I have deployed child theme and after that, I have run these commands

[image: Front End]

[image: Back end****]

Comment: Have you multi store?

Comment: yes There are multi store

Comment: deploy in all stores and check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `setup:upgrade` without updating static content using the `--keep-generated` flag. Here is full example (for the `www-data` user and running using default php interpreter on ubuntu):

```
sudo -u www-data php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
```

Comment: I have applied it as well but still same

Comment: @HafsaZulfiqar it could be permission issue. Check is you are using right user when run a command.

Comment: But when I enable the production mode then It works fine

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run "php bin/magento s:s:d" 
command which is for static content deployment that keeps the static files in you cache.
Basically after every time you run setup:upgrade it will destroy all the cached files that's why you need to run this command after upgrade.